# How to setup broadband connection on Fedora23?

Tags: linux, fedora

This is how I setup broadband connetion on Window7 with DHCP IP.
[image]

[image]

But how can I setup this connection on Fedora 23 ?
In Fedora23 Workstation(Gnome), I see this:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Sorry I didn't find anything with "xDSL", I don't know why.

Comment: What is your ISP?

Comment: I'm in a chinese university, it's the university uniform network service, in Win7, only set auto-IP, and setup broadband connection, use my school ID and password, then I can connect the Internet.

Comment: I'm no expert, I cannot say exactly what is my ISP. But i'm sure in university, we don't use static IP, we use auto-IP plus broadband connection on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must start by enabling `NetworkManager` by following the [instructions here](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/11/html/User_Guide/sect-User_Guide-Connecting_to_the_Internet-NetworkManager.html).

Once that is enabled, you will see a new icon for it but you can also open it this way:

> To launch the Network Configuration Tool in KDE, navigate to the KMenu > Applications > System > Network menu entry. When working as a regular user the application prompts for the root password. (extract from [Fedora official documentation](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/11/html/User_Guide/sect-User_Guide-Connecting_to_the_Internet-KDE.html))

Finally, from the Network configuration tool, [the documentation](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/11/html/User_Guide/sect-User_Guide-Connecting_to_the_Internet-Configuring_PPPoE.html) says to `click the New Button and then choose XDSL Configuration from the left hand column, clicking the Next button to proceed.
In the following screen, enter the name of the xDSL provider, and the username and password belonging to this account.`

Comment: That shows you how to setup a PPPoE connection which corresponds to your Windows example.  That may not be the way your university needs you to connect.  Most network connections are simply configured automatically when you plug the cable.

Comment: Let me know if it works or not.

Comment: Hi... I tried, but I didn't work it out, I updated some information, please check it again.

Comment: Can you confirm that you followed the instructions in the first link?

Comment: In Fedora Workstation 23, there seems no such "System > Administration > Services " things.